# showing result of file call by ajax request into different div

Tags: php, ajax

On button click I submit the form and post some data to `data.php`.

The result Of `data.php` I show in some `div` on index.php

index.php:

```
function showUser(form, e) {
      //alert(myid);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue=false;
      var xmlhttp;
      var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;  
      var text1 = document.getElementById('previewUrl').innerText || document.getElementById('previewUrl').textContent;
      var text2 = document.getElementById('previewTitle').innerText || document.getElementById('previewTitle').textContent;
      var text3 = document.getElementById('previewDescription').innerText || document.getElementById('previewDescription').textContent;

      //alert(text3);      
      console.log(sent);

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;

document.getElementById("myFirstDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
document.getElementById("mySecondDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      deURIComponent(text3);
      xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&text1=' + text1 + '&text2=' + text2 + '&text3=' + text3);
    }
```

Data.php looks like this:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text1=$_POST['text1'];
$text2=$_POST['text2'];
$text3=$_POST['text3'];

//Some processing

echo $restult1;  // I want to show this on <div1> on main page   index.php

//Some processsing

echo $result2;    // I want to show this on <div2> on main page index.php


?>
```

**HOW can I show result1 and result2 on different div on index.php?**

Comment: You can't use jquery ajax to make things easier?

Comment: @JensonMJohn: Like Nikolas explained, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text1=$_POST['text1'];
$text2=$_POST['text2'];
$text3=$_POST['text3'];

//Some processing


$resultArray = array("resultOne" => $result1,"resultTwo" => $result2);

echo json_encode($resultArray);

?>
```

So you will get a response object from php page.

And now you can access it values like bellow in Js

**In Javascript**

```
xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;
```

Now you can set for two divs

```
document.getElementById("myFirstDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
document.getElementById("mySecondDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;
```

Comment: For my above case in function `ShowUser()` where and how can I get `resultOne` and `resultTwo;`

Comment: thanks a ton. Can you please exalpain for `xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;` and where to place them? I have edited my question code. PLease update it if wrong

Comment: I could not put `xmlhttp.responseText.resultOne;
xmlhttp.responseText.resultTwo;
` correctly:

Comment: still Testing. Needs improvment. Actual problem is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609896/getting-value-from-file-called-by-ajax-request-using-json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40051/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-samitha)

Comment: can you please check it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could echo a script where you assign the value of `result1` to `div1` and `result2` to `div2`.

For example if you use jquery you could do something like this:

```
echo "<script> $("#div1").innerHTML(".$result1");</script>"
```